# How to get linq `ForEach` statement to return data on the method call being made for each list object?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, foreach, linq-to-entities

I have a linq `ForEach` statement that calls a method for each `Report` object in the list. This method returns an array of data tables for each call and I want to somehow get that returned data. How can I do this using linq ForEach rather than the old school `foreach (var x in x's) { ... }`? Here is my code:

```
Reports.ForEach(r => r.LoadTableData(Event, Human, Animal, exData));
```

How can I get back each `DataTable[]` that `LoadTableData` is returning?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
var tables = Reports.Select(r => r.LoadTableData(Event, Human, Animal, exData));
```

`Select` *maps* a collection onto another (in this case, a collection of `Report` into a collection of `DataTable[]`). In fact, the `Select` method is often called `map` in other languages such as Scala and Ruby.

`ForEach` executes an arbitrary action for each element in the source collection.

And btw, `ForEach` is not part of the LINQ extensions. It's just another method on `List<T>`.

Comment: Ohhh very good to know. Thought it was part of linq because that's the only time I've really used it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I found this after making ForEachWithReturn<T, TResult> extension method.